# Assert on Page Refresh Coded UI

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests, page-refresh

I have a test that needs to verify that an autorefresh property has been set.  My first thought would be to `.WaitForControlExist()` on a loading page that happens when the page refreshes but Coded UI is too slow to capture that control as it disappears after a half second or so.

My question is whether or not there is a method that will wait for the page to be refreshed that has some sort of timeout similar to WaitForControlExist()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a grid on the page that displays certain data. What I ended up doing was setting up the auto-refresh, adding more data to the grid, waiting the specified time, and verifying that the additional data was present.

Automated testing takes a lot of creativity sometimes you have to attack it from the side.

Answer (score 0):

You might me using `.WaitForControlExist()` with come click of control . in place of that you can use `if(uIabc.Exists)` or any control. But once control is there it will be chased and you might need to create new objects for control dynamically at run time.